# how to use an index variable for a recursive function?

Tags: c++, recursion

How can I use an index variable for a recursive function that  increments every time the function is called so it can return a value without passing it as a parameter or using static or global variables as I want to call this function more than one time not only once.

Here's my code:

```
bool isAlphabetic(string s)
{
    static int i = 0;
    if (i==s.size())
    {
        return true;
    }
    else if (!isalpha(s[i])){
        return false;
    }
    i++;
    return isAlphabetic(s);
}
```

Does any body know how to fix this? I know i'm using a static variable but this makes the function run correctly the first time its called but not after that.

Comment: @2501 I don't want to pass it as an argument. is there any possible way to do this than passing an argument?

Comment: How the heck do you expect to hold status information without storing it somewhere either as a passed-in parameter or in some other variable?

Comment: What is the behaviour you see and how does it differ from what you expect?

Comment: @ApprenticeQueue this is a lab assignment and i am required to do this without passing 'i' as a parameter

Comment: You do not want to pass the position, but you use a string copy on each call. That's MUCH worst, even if the string buffer doesn't get copy each time.

Answer (score 4):

Worth noting that the recursion may fail with larger strings due to stack overflow.

```
bool isAlphabetic(const string & s, int pos){
    if(i==s.size()) return true;
    else if(!isalpha(s[pos])) return false;
    return isAlphabetic(s, ++pos);
}

bool isAlphabetic(const string & s){
    return isAlphabetic(s, 0);
}
```

Comment: A smart compiler would prevent stack overflow because this algorithm is tail-recursive.

Comment: Not (necessarily) in debug mode! :)

Comment: At least you use a reference to the string which alleviates the *horrible* copy.